# Start/stop a timer when a specific application is opened

Tags: android, timer

I was wondering if there are any methods I could use to find out when a selected application is opened/closed. For example, while this application is running in the background, if Facebook is opened, this is returned to the application and a timer starts. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to approach this problem is by verifying the list of processes that are running and by checking their importance level which could be anywhere from Foreground process to Empty process, by using [RunningAppProcessInfo#importance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html#importance).

The one you are interested in is of course, the foreground process.
Quoting the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle):

> Foreground process
>
> A process that is required for what the user is
>   currently doing. A process is considered to be in the foreground if
>   any of the following conditions are true:
>
> It hosts an Activity that
>   the user is interacting with (the Activity's onResume() method has
>   been called).
>
> It hosts a Service that's bound to the activity that the
>   user is interacting with. It hosts a Service that's running "in the
>   foreground"—the service has called startForeground().
>
> It hosts a
>   Service that's executing one of its lifecycle callbacks (onCreate(),
>   onStart(), or onDestroy()).
>
> It hosts a BroadcastReceiver that's
>   executing its onReceive() method.
>
> Generally, only a few foreground
>   processes exist at any given time. They are killed only as a last
>   resort—if memory is so low that they cannot all continue to run.
>   Generally, at that point, the device has reached a memory paging
>   state, so killing some foreground processes is required to keep the
>   user interface responsive.

The problem is that there could be a couple false positives, if it falls into one of the 2 last categories (*Service* or *BroadcastReceiver*). But I believe, this is the closer you could get. You might be able to eliminate those false positives by checking additionally [the importanceReasonCode field](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html#importanceReasonCode).

Another challenge is to know when to check for this information. Polling is a bad idea since you will be draining a lot of battery, but that could be acceptable if you only do it during a short/specific timeframe during which you will be polling at regular intervals to get an estimation of how much time an application has been running.

**[EDIT]**

A snippet that shows how to iterate through the running processes and determine the importance level, as well as get the packages related to those processes.

```
  public void findRunningApps() {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)     
        context.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        for (RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()) {
            if(processInfo.importance == IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
               for (String packageName : processInfo.pkgList) {

               }
            } 
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, will look into this in more detail and get back to you.

Comment: @escull638 I added a snippet to show how to get the information you need.